# Using LAG function with a specific condition

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions, lag

I have a table in below format.

[image]

I am able to convert the table to below format using LAG function in oracle SQL.

[image]

However, I want this result table to be created in such a way that for rows where status is 'ON', to_date should provide the date of next 'OFF' date.  Below is how it should look like.

[image]

How can we do this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want a conditional `lead()` with option `ignore nulls`:

```
select 
    id,
    date from_date,
    case when status = 'ON' 
        then lead(case when status = 'OFF' then date end ignore nulls) 
            over(partition by id order by date)
    end to_date,
    status
from mytable
```

To better match the expected results, we apply the function to any status other than `'OFF'`, and withdraw 1 day from the result:

```
select 
    id,
    date from_date,
    case when status <> 'OFF' 
        then lead(case when status = 'OFF' then date end ignore nulls) 
            over(partition by id order by date) - 1
    end to_date,
    status
from mytable
```

If you also want the next `'ON'` date for `'OFF'` rows:

```
select 
    id,
    date from_date,
    case when status <> 'OFF' 
        then lead(case when status = 'OFF' then date end ignore nulls) 
            over(partition by id order by date) - 1
        else lead(case when status = 'ON' then date end ignore nulls) 
            over(partition by id order by date) - 1
    end to_date,
    status
from mytable
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8e14d908461f14a325f22bc129bdf98)**

First query:

```
   ID | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE   | STATUS
----: | :-------- | :-------- | :-----
15643 | 10-MAR-20 | 20-MAR-20 | ON    
15643 | 15-MAR-20 | null      | test  
15643 | 20-MAR-20 | null      | OFF
```

Second query:

```
   ID | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE   | STATUS
----: | :-------- | :-------- | :-----
15643 | 10-MAR-20 | 19-MAR-20 | ON    
15643 | 15-MAR-20 | 19-MAR-20 | test  
15643 | 20-MAR-20 | null      | OFF
```

Third query (you can't see the difference with the second query since there is no `'OFF'` row with a next `'ON'`):

```
   ID | FROM_DATE | TO_DATE   | STATUS
----: | :-------- | :-------- | :-----
15643 | 10-MAR-20 | 19-MAR-20 | ON    
15643 | 15-MAR-20 | 19-MAR-20 | test  
15643 | 20-MAR-20 | null      | OFF
```